# Error: "unable to start activity ComponentInfo... Java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

So I've been researching this issue and found that this issue seems to occur when it can't reach something I'm referencing in my Activity. I think the issue might lie in me trying to reach the class Application but I'm not sure. I've tried commenting out the intents that relate to geocoding and still got the same error so I'm not really sure where its finding a null pointer.

This is the error code I'm getting:

```
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183): Process: com.binarsunset.topic, PID: 23183
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.binarsunset.topic/com.binarsunset.topic.CreateTopicActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at com.binarsunset.topic.CreateTopicActivity.updateCharacterCountTextViewText(CreateTopicActivity.java:118)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at com.binarsunset.topic.CreateTopicActivity.onCreate(CreateTopicActivity.java:71)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
05-17 01:50:11.583: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    ... 11 more
```

So I start in activity TopicActivity but it is not my main, here is the code for that:

```
package com.binarsunset.topic;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

/**
 * Created by Douglas on 5/3/2015.
 */
public class TopicActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_topic);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.topic_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.Create: {
                aboutItemCreate();
                return true;
            }


            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void aboutItemCreate(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateTopicActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

I click Create activity on the action bar which will take me to CreateTopicActivity and that is where it crashes here is the code for CreateTopicAcvivity:

```
package com.binarsunset.topic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseGeoPoint;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

/**
 * Created by Douglas on 5/16/2015.
 */
public class CreateTopicActivity extends Activity {

    // UI references.
    private EditText createTopicEditText;
    private TextView characterCountTextView;
    private Button createButton;

    private int maxCharacterCount = Application.getConfigHelper().getPostMaxCharacterCount();
    private ParseGeoPoint geoPoint;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_topic);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(Application.INTENT_EXTRA_LOCATION);
        geoPoint = new ParseGeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        createTopicEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.create_topic_title);
        createTopicEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                updateTopicButtonState();
                updateCharacterCountTextViewText();
            }
        });

        characterCountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.character_count_textview);

        createButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_topic_button);
        createButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createTopic();
            }
        });

        updateTopicButtonState();
        updateCharacterCountTextViewText();
    }

    private void createTopic () {
        String text = createTopicEditText.getText().toString().trim();

        // Set up a progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(CreateTopicActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.progress_topic));
        dialog.show();

        // Create a post.
        AnywallPost topic = new AnywallPost();

        // Set the location to the current user's location
        topic.setLocation(geoPoint);
        topic.setText(text);
        topic.setUser(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        topic.setInt(1);
        ParseACL acl = new ParseACL();

        // Give public read access
        acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        topic.setACL(acl);

        // Save the topic
        topic.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private String getTopicEditTextText () {
        return createTopicEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    }

    private void updateTopicButtonState () {
        int length = getTopicEditTextText().length();
        boolean enabled = length > 0 && length < maxCharacterCount;
        createButton.setEnabled(enabled);
    }

    private void updateCharacterCountTextViewText () {
        String characterCountString = String.format("%d/%d", createTopicEditText.length(), maxCharacterCount);
        characterCountTextView.setText(characterCountString);
    }

}
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.binarsunset.topic"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.binarsunset.Topic.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.parse.anywall.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <!--
     The following permission is not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but is recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCVz0h90fBZwkcgagi1Q7WV1W_cVgd0_QA" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_signup"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".DispatchActivity"
            android:noHistory="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PostActivity"
            android:label="@string/activity_post_title"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TopicActivity"
            android:label="Topic" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PostCommentsActivity"
            android:label="PostComments" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LocationActivity"
            android:label="Location" />

        <activity
            android:name=".CreateTopicActivity"
            android:label="CreateTopic" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my activity_create_topic.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".PostActivity"
>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/create_topic_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="@string/create_topic_title"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_above="@+id/create_topic_details">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/create_topic_details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/character_count_Create_Details"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="@string/create_topic_details"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:gravity="top" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/create_topic_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="@string/Create_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/character_count_Create_Details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_above="@id/create_topic_button"
        android:text="@string/character_count_placeholder"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if you need any additional code. Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Also I commented out everything but the layout creator in my CreateTopicActivity and it ran without crashing so it seems the problem lies in code of CreateTopicActivity. Which leads me to believe its either the geocoding or the references to Application but even if I knew that was the error I'm still new to this so I really don't know how I would fix the problem or why that is a problem in the first place.

Comment: Mark line number 118, of your CreateTopicActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pointing to the View which is not in the activity layout returns NULL**

The TextView which you are referring by the id `character_count_textview` is doesn't exist in the activity layout `activity_create_topic`. So the NULL POINTER Exception occurred.

Comment: @gunR POST Your `activity_create_topic.xml` layout. i think the TextView which you're pointing with the `character_count_textview` is not in THAT layout.

Comment: Ok I added it, I think you may be right about that, I'm going to change that right now and test it.

Comment: Yep, That was the issue, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `characterCountTextView` before initializing your `createTopicEditText` as shown below

```
    characterCountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.character_count_textview);
    createTopicEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.create_topic_title);
    createTopicEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override 
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        } 

        @Override 
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            updateTopicButtonState(); 
            updateCharacterCountTextViewText(); 
        } 
    });
```

Notice that in your code `characterCountTextView` is not yet initialized when you call `updateCharacterCountTextViewText()` method from your 
        createTopicEditTexts TextChangedListener

Comment: Hmm, I added both the UI declaration and the onCreate declaration but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

i think your maxCharacterCount is null.

Try moving the below line of code to onCreate.

```
  maxCharacterCount = Application.getConfigHelper().getPostMaxCharacterCount();
```

like below

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_topic);

   maxCharacterCount = Application.getConfigHelper().getPostMaxCharacterCount();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(Application.INTENT_EXTRA_LOCATION);
    geoPoint = new ParseGeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    characterCountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.character_count_textview);
    createTopicEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.create_topic_title);
    createTopicEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            updateTopicButtonState();
            updateCharacterCountTextViewText();
        }
    });

    createButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_topic_button);
    createButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createTopic();
        }
    });

    updateTopicButtonState();
    updateCharacterCountTextViewText();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because of `updateCharacterCountTextViewText ()` method just debug and see both `createTopicEditText` and `maxCharacterCount` are not null And move  `characterCountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.character_count_textview);` to before `createTopicEditText.addTextChanged` method